# TinyMCE and ActiveAdmin for Rails

Tags: tinymce, activeadmin

I am reacquainting myself with Rails and I am really liking Active Admin.  I would like to get tinyMCE working with it for use in text areas.  However, any instructions I find are incomplete.  For some reason, I think that I am missing something really simple here.

So, for example, I have tinymce-rails installed (3.4.9) and followed the instructions (https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails).  However, here's where I think I failed:  actually initiating tinyMCE.  According to the doc, I have two options:

1. use the <%= tinymce %> helper or...
2. initialize it like the following `tinyMCE.init({
   mode: 'textareas',
   theme: 'advanced'
   });`

I tried adding the latter to my active_admin.js file to no avail.

If someone could guide me on this, I would be most appreciative.

Comment: the second should work usually, do you get any js-errors then?

Answer (score 15):

I got it working doing the following things (outside of the install described at the [repo](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails))

In admin/my_class.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyClass do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs do 
      f.input :body, :input_html => { :class => "tinymce" }
    end
  end
end
```

In initializers/active_admin.rb:

```
...
config.register_javascript 'tinymce.js'
```

This was what actually got the tinymce.js script to show up in the head of the admin layout.

In javascripts/active_admin.js:

```
//= require active_admin/base
//= require tinymce

$(document).ready(function() {
  tinyMCE.init({
     mode: 'textareas',
     theme: 'advanced'
   });
});
```

After doing those things, that body input (text area) had a fully functioning editor on it.

Comment: Good documentation. Works with rails 3.2.13, active_admin 0.6.0, and tinymce-rails 3.5.8.2.

Comment: Add `editor_selector: 'tinymce'` to `tinyMCE.init` so that only specific textareas have the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: for you who has coffescript instead of pure javascript, convert your `tinyMCE.init` into coffe with this tool http://js2.coffee/

Answer (score 0):

Do your textarea inputs have a 'class' attribute or something that tinyMCE can hook into? Does it work from the javascript console (firefox/chrome)?  Have you checked the presence of tinymce.js in the head(source) of your page.

I got it working with a form partial, and I had to give a class to the input element so tinymce could hook to it.

```
<%= f.input :literature_nld, :input_html => { :class => 'tinymce', :size => "80x4" } %>
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks.  Your response triggered another thought about whether or not tinymce.js was in the head of my page.  The tinymce-rails documentation was a little unclear on this.  It turns out that by adding a call to this in my active_admin.rb file, I was able to get it to show.

Many thanks for all your help!

Comment: Would have been nice though if you had accepted my answer, I should have just commented.