# How to add tinymce-rails gem in activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, activeadmin, tinymce-rails

I am using [active admin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) gem in my Rails application.In that, I have a resources article and user and I need to use [TinyMCE-rails](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails) in the article. 
It is possible to add if possible how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of [WYSISWG editor plugins for ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Plugins#wysiwyg-editor). The TinyMCE plugin has not been updated for a while so I don't know its status.  A couple of the others are more current.

Comment: I don't use acts-as-taggable. There is an old [comment on the wiki](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/How-to-work-with-acts-as-taggable-on) Please posts questions on StackOverflow so others can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a bit late but in hopes that this may help someone else in the future - TinyMCE is active and the [tinymce-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/tinymce-rails) gem is actively maintained (latest release as of writing is just under 2 months old). Getting this to work in ActiveAdmin is not too hard, the [github](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails) page and [TinyMCE and ActiveAdmin for Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10406987/) post tell you most of what you need but here is what I did:

1. add the tinymce-rails gem - bundle install
2. add TinyMCE assets by adding `//= require tinymce` to `application.js`
3. register `tinymce.js` in `active_admin.js` and initialize it by adding the following to your `active_admin.js` file (this was the missing key for me):

```
...
//= require tinymce
...
// initialize tinymce
$(document).ready(function() {
  tinyMCE.init({
     selector: 'textarea.editor',
     browsser_spellcheck: true,
     menubar: 'edit view insert format tools table help',
     plugins: 'code image link lists media preview table'
   });
});
```

To use it in a form:

```
...
f.input :description, input_html: {rows: 4, class: 'editor'}
...
```

Hope this helps someone down the road.